# What's the typespec declaration for a function that may raise?

Tags: elixir

Using [Elixir's typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html), how do I document in `@spec` that a function may raise an exception instead of returning a value?

Answer (score 19):

### Nothing

At one time, `no_return()` ([listed in the Typespecs docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#built-in-types)) was used in various places to document that a function might raise an exception - eg, [`File.copy!/2` in Elixir 1.6](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6/lib/elixir/lib/file.ex#L614).

But those uses were removed by Devon Estes [in this PR](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/8092), and in approving it, José Valim said:

> Any function can fail any time in face of invalid input.

I take this to mean that "this function could possibly raise an error" is always assumed and need not be documented in the typespec.

Comment: This is a valueless copy of the documentation on type specs, even lacking a reference to it. http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html

Comment: @mudasobwa I wrote this question and answer. Neither the Erlang page you linked nor the Elixir typespec documentation page I linked in the question mentions the word "raise" or "raises", so neither came up in a web search for me regarding this scenario. I found the answer by looking at the Elixir `File` module source, which I linked. The fact that you can find the answer to this question in the docs given that you already know it does not mean it's not useful to document this in a way that can be found by search users (though I may later do a PR to the Elixir docs to make it explicit there).

Comment: @NathanLong it's not explicitly stated but it is there:  *Some functions in Erlang are not meant to return; either because they define servers or because they are used to throw exceptions, as in the following function:

  my_error(Err) -> erlang:throw({error, Err}).

For such functions, it is recommended to use the special no_return() type for their "return", through a contract of the following form:

  -spec my_error(term()) -> no_return().*

Comment: @mudasobwa I would add that it's pretty frustrating to me that you would downvote this answer. I don't need the points and already know the answer; the sole reason that I posted this question is to help other developers. I've been around since the S.O. beta and have always understood that the purpose of this site is to make the answers to common programming questions easily findable by search. This wasn't, and now it is. Please do not downvote things that would be useful to others simply because they wouldn't be useful to you.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Good catch. However 1) not all Elixir users will search for that term 2) not all Elixir users will think to look at the Erlang docs when working with Elixir typespecs. Searching `elixir typespec exception` does not find the Erlang docs. I maintain that the Q&A has value for search.

Comment: I would immediately retract the downvote as soon as you have the documentation linked, not the _very_ obsolete source code of the ancient Elixir version.

Comment: Elixir removed all `no_return()` in the specs. So I think this answer need to be updated. See https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/8092

Comment: @darkbaby123 Good catch. Updated.